# AngularJS rootscope variables not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS 1.4.7, i got a `$rootScope` function

```
$rootScope.validate = function(data){
 if(data.FirstName.length=5){
  $rootScope.isValid =true
 }
}
```

The `$rootScope.isValid` gets "console.logged" but the isValid field can not detect the change

Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you call `validate()`? Also why are you putting functions and variables on `$rootScope`?

Comment: I am calling it from a controller, and yes i know its bad practice now, wont happen again. but its too late to make any changes!

Comment: Unless it is a typo, your if statement should contain `===` not `=`.

Comment: I would encourage you to not take the attitude of "I know this isn't right but it's too late to do it right now"...  That only leads you to some very difficult to test and maintain code.

Comment: In addition to @MattWay's comment, `data.FirstName.length=5` will **always** be *truthy* so `$rootScope.isValid` will always be `true`

Comment: @Claies thanks for the advice but with a deadline tommorrow, it is necessary sadly.

Comment: And guys it was a typo not in the = but just a spelling mistake in isValid thanks for your time